# HTML anchor behaviour same as without anchor on middle mouse

Tags: javascript, html, click, anchor

How can i make that this link:

```
<a href="index.html#anchorTarget">Go</a>
```

behaves as if it was this link:

```
<a href="index.html">Go</a>
```

if the middle mouse button was clicked? (On my machine the second opens the target in a new tab, which is what i would expect to happen if i use the middle mouse button).

Or: Why should this different behaviour be a good idea?

Javascript is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to hijack the middle mouse click and load the page with a scroll parameter passed another way (like via POST) or you could load the page dynamically and scroll to the correct position. If either of those solutions work for you, I can provide code samples to help you down that path.

Comment: This is not the point. Even in the javascript i don't know what the default behaviour is of the middle mouse click (open in the same tab, new tab, or even open in a new window).